# how to shrink the header on scrolling in android

Tags: android

I want to shrink the header part on scrooing in my app.
Similar to the below link..

http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/AnimatedHeader/

please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these libraries:

**FadingActionBar** https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar

**Header2ActionBar** https://github.com/AChep/Header2ActionBar